# Inverse Chebyshev Recurrence

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, chebyshev-polynomials

The Chebyshev polynomials (of the first kind) are a sequence of polynomials defined recursively by
$$
\begin{cases}
T_{0}(x) = 1 \\
T_{1}(x) = x \\
T_{n}(x) = 2xT_{n-1}(x) - T_{n-2}(x)
\end{cases}
$$

I'll refer to [Mathematica](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html) for all other properties, which I haven't needed so far.

Using this recurrence relation, it is easy to expand given lineair combinations of Chebyshev polynomials as linear combinations of powers of $x$. What I do in Matlab, is I choose an upper bound $n$ for the degree of polynomials I'll be working with and then write the conversion out explicitly in matrix form. For example, if $n = 4$, I'd have:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
     1&     0&    -1&     0&     1 \\
     0&     1&     0&    -3&     0 \\
     0&     0&     2&     0&    -8 \\
     0&     0&     0&     4&     0 \\
     0&     0&     0&     0&     8
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the columns are constructed from left to right using the recurrence relation.
If $c$ is a vector of coefficients of a polynomial (of degree $\leq 4$) with respect to the Chebyshev basis, then its coefficients with respect to the monomial basis are simply given as $A \cdot c$.

If I want to go the other way around, that is, rewriting a linear combination of powers of x as a linear combination of Chebyshev polynomials, I can just invert this matrix. Needless to say, this fails numerically as soon as $n$ gets large enough (the elements on the main diagonal of $A$ are powers of 2). I was wondering if there is a better way to obtain this inverse matrix, perhaps by using some inverse recurrence formula?

Kind regards

Nicolas

Comment: Inverting the matrix isn't required. Any polynomial of degree $n  =  c_n T_n + $ some polynomial of degree $n-1$ with $c_n$ easily computable. Use recursively this procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assume you're talking about using euclidean division?

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate?

Answer (score 6):

We may think to this problem in these terms: to write $T_n(x)$ as a linear combination of monomials is the same as expressing $\cos(nx)$ in terms of $\cos(x),\cos^2(x),\ldots$ On the other hand, to express $x^n$ in terms of $T_0(x),\ldots,T_n(x)$ is the same as expressing $\cos(x)^n$ in terms of $1,\cos(x),\cos(2x),\ldots$, i.e. to compute the Fourier cosine series of $\cos(x)^n$. That is an easy task through the binomial theorem, since:

$$ \cos^n(x) = \left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^n = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}e^{(n-2j)ix}\tag{1}$$
gives:
$$ \cos^{2n}(x)=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}+\frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n+j}\cos(2jx)\tag{2}$$
so:
$$ x^{2n} = \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}+\frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n+j} T_{2j}(x).\tag{3}$$
The odd case is similar.

The solution to the inverse problem is given by the formula $(15)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html): it can be achieved through the binomial theorem, too. This sheds some light on the relation between the [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) and the inversion of structured matrices ([Toeplitz matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Toeplitz_matrix), in this case) through [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) or Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to implement is as soon as I have the time. Let's hope this will yield better results for higher $n$ ($ 80 < n < 200$).

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is in triangular form. The reversion is like a back substitution step in Gaussian elimination. Look at it this way:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\-1&0&2&0&0\\0&-3&0&4&0\\1&0&-8&0&8\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}T_0\\T_1\\T_2\\T_3\\T_4\end{pmatrix}$$

You are solve this triangular system. Start from the first equation:
$$x_1=T_0\\x_2=T_1\\x_3=\frac{1}{2}(T_2+T_0)\\\cdots $$

In Matlab, you can write a for loop to easily solve this.

And since the matrix is always triangular, even the inverse is not too bad.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think implementing this loop will yield better results than just inverting? I would think that is exactly what Matlab would do.

Comment: @Nicolas: Yes, I would think Matlab is smart enough to do this for a triangular matrix. That's why I said even the inverse process is not too bad. I found this old post in 1997, which says Matlab can recognize an upper triangular matrix and do farward/backward substitution. I am not sure whether they have improved it so it can do the same trick for lower triangular matrix now. You can try this method and see the flops too. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/2558

Comment: I thought so. Still, the results are okay but not great when just using the Matlab inverse. By expanding the 6 x 6 matrix I gave even further to obtain a 81 x 81 matrix $ B $, the calculation $ BB^{-1} $ yields a matrix with elements of order of magnitude $10^{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(x)$ be the polynomial you want to be expressed as $\sum c_k T_k(x)$. The Chebyshev polynomials are orthogonal with respect to the following inner product:
$$
\langle T_k, T_l\rangle \equiv \sum_{j=1}^n T_k(x_j) T_l(x_j) = \begin{cases}
n, & k = l = 0\\
\frac{n}{2}, & 0 < k = l < n\\
0, & k \neq l,\, k,l < n
\end{cases}
$$
Here $x_k, k = 1,\dots,n$ are roots of $T_n(x)$ polynomial, which have simple form (due to $T_n(x) = \cos n \arccos x$)
$$
x_k = \cos \left(\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi\right), \quad k = 1, \dots, n
$$
Using this orthogonality you can express $c_k$ as
$$
c_k = \frac{\langle T_k, P\rangle}{\langle T_k, T_k\rangle}
$$

**Edit**. Also, if you care about numerical stability (especially when $n$ is big) you should not compute $T_n(x)$ by direct summation of 
$$
T_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k
$$
but rather using explicit 
$$
T_n(x) = \cos n \arccos x
$$
or using the recurrence relation
$$
T_n(x) = 2xT_{n-1}(x) - T_{n-2}(x).
$$
Even computing
$$
T_n(x) = 2^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^n (x - x_k)
$$
is very sensitive to reordering of the multipliers (noticeable when $n \gtrsim 100$). The optimal reordering was given in [Lebedev, V. I., and S. A. Finogenov. "Solution of the parameter ordering problem in Chebyshev iterative methods." USSR Computational Mathematics and Mathematical Physics 13.1 (1974): 21-41.](http://ocean.sci-hub.bz/12f2e82611faabeb98a65e3e898ef580/lebedev1974.pdf)

Comment: Very interesting approach, sounds like the most promising strategy so far when only a single polynomial needs to be converted. Thank you very much, I'll try to implement this strategy tomorrow.

Comment: You can convert the polynomial basis $1, x, x^2, \dots$ and use the linear combination for every polynomial you need. In other words, the inverse matrix has the form $$(A^{-1})_{ij} = \frac{\langle T_j, x^i\rangle}{\langle T_j, T_j\rangle}$$.

Comment: @Nicolas the matrix $A$ is badly scaled, its condition number is $6\cdot 10^{29}$ for $n=81$ as reported by Matlab. That means it's invese is not representable using double precision unless you tolerate errors about $10^{13}$

Comment: So it would be more desirable to use your intial conversion formula rather than the matrix multiplication?

Comment: That worth a try at least. Or just use arbitrary precision arithmetic for that task

Comment: Will do, I'll let you know how it worked tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

To try these methods, I've taken some of my problems (e.g. partial sums of Taylor series), converted them to the Chebyshev basis and then converted them back.
For my purposes, I've found none of the given answers to be more effective than the Matlab inverse.

- Jack D'Aurizio's answer, while interesting, provides little numerical stability.
- KittyL's answer yields more or less the same results as the Matlab inverse, confirming that Matlab efficiently inverts diagonal matrices.
- uranix' answer, against my own expectations, isn't stable either, not even for low degree polynomials (degree < 20)