# Is it possible to express higher odd powers of cosine in terms of only first order of cosine?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

- I have an equation:

$$\cos^n \left(\frac{\gamma t}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = \cos(\omega t),$$ where $\gamma \equiv \gamma(t)$ is a function of time, $\omega$ and $n$ are positive constants.

- I want to know if I can somehow get a continuous and integrable form of $\gamma(t)$ from this. For that to happen, first of all the equation must be true. Of course, for even orders of $n$ that is LHS is always positive, but RHS can be negative too. So $n$ can be assumed odd.

(But I also feel if we were able to express higher odd orders in terms of the lowest odd order, then why would we have Fourier series with summation going to infinite orders?)

- I tried with $\gamma(t) = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2t}\arccos{(\cos^{\frac{1}{n}}{(\omega t)})}$. But I could not integrate it.
- Also, found by differentiating and manipulation $\gamma(t) = \frac{\omega}{2\sqrt{n}}\tan(\omega t) \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sec^{\frac{2}{n}}(\omega t)-1}}$. But this wasn't easy to integrate either. Are there other forms?

Comment: You might check out the answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326311/inverse-chebyshev-recurrence).

Comment: @WaylandBales, thanks for linking that question! Especially the first answer seems to provide a useful technique.

Comment: You may be interested in Chebyshev polynomials. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials